# MongoDB evaluation query expressions in C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I stumbled upon the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) feature in MongoDB 3.6. I want to use it in conjunction with change streams to only receive updates if property A of the updated document is greater than property B.

```
db.items.find({ $expr: { $gt: [ "$A" , "$B" ] } });
```

Is the feature implemented in the C# driver? I'm using the Builders to build the pipeline filters, but didn't find the appropriate methods for the $expr operator.

Comment: No it is not implemented for LINQ yet, and there probably isn't a real match for it. You can construct `BsonDocument` for any MongoDB operation which does not have such an equivalent.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate.. Thank you!

Comment: The best you can do it project the value and match in a different stage. It's a separation of stages of course as `$project` and `$match` unless you put the BSON expression in yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently come across this too, I ended up going for the follow option of just writing out the query as a string for the match pipeline

```cs
var cursor = _collection.Watch(PipelineDefinition<YourType, YourType>.Create(
  new[]
  {
    PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match<BsonDocument>(@"{ $expr: { $eq: [ ""$A"" , ""$B"" ] }  }")
  }));
```